# Build size - Assets are small, but build is still large

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, assets

My app in Unity3D reports itself as quite small - 11.3M total (it's a simple game) including music and textures.

```
Textures      1.5 kb     0.0% 
Meshes        0.0 kb     0.0% 
Animations    0.0 kb     0.0% 
Sounds        6.3 mb     55.8% 
Shaders       406.5 kb   3.5% 
Other Assets  82.8 kb    0.7% 
Levels        28.6 kb    0.2% 
Scripts       558.1 kb   4.8% 
Included DLLs 3.9 mb     34.8% 
File headers  9.5 kb     0.1% 
Complete size 11.3 mb    100.0%
```

However, the iOS build when I upload to TestFlight is 236M, and downloading a quarter of a gigabyte for a simple game is not ideal (it's a non-dev build with no symbols).

Can anyone suggest where I start to tackle this?  Every article I can find focuses on reducing your asset sizes, but mine are already small, so something else is going on.